# how to move to lightbox from another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How can we open another dive from light box. Actually we need to open lightbox at the time the present one should be closed.

here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/m9RaN/1/) link

Comment: haven't you try to view source of frame with lighboxes?)

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code. All of your code simply targets `.box`, so there is no distinguishing which box you want to open anywhere. Note that both your links open the same box. Your "next" button and your "prev" button (the latter of which you'll never see) both just have the "close" class, there is not even an attempt to open *any* lightbox.